# Codename One UWP release build crash on start

Tags: uwp, build, codenameone

I have a Codename One UWP app that works fine when I build it in debug mode and install the appxbundle using the supplied PowerShell script. However, when I build in release (appxupload) mode the resulting app (extracted from the appxupload file) crashes immediately after showing its window on startup. I thought it might be an issue with local install but when I submitted the app to the Windows store they reported the same behaviour.

I have recreated the problem with a blank project containing only this in start():

```
Form form = new Form("Test", new BorderLayout());
form.show();
```

And built it using these settings:

```
codename1.arg.windows.buildType=Release
codename1.arg.windows.makeReleaseAppxbundle=false
codename1.arg.windows.platforms=x86|x64|ARM
```

The error in the windows event viewer says:

```
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.18362.997, time stamp: 0xe85f9394
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x0000000000713500
```

I tried with makeReleaseAppxbundle=true and that creates a working appxbundle file for the test program. Unfortunately the build takes a very long time for the test program (over 5 times as long) and fails after about 15 minutes for my main app with this error:

```
 [exec]   Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
 [exec]      at Microsoft.Cci.ISymUnmanagedWriter2.Close()
 [exec]      at Microsoft.Cci.PdbWriter.Finalize()
```

Comment: This might be a regression we'll look into it

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this.  I've reproduced the problem, and applied a hotfix to the build server.   I'm now able to build apps

```
codename1.arg.windows.buildType=Release
codename1.arg.windows.makeReleaseAppxbundle=true
codename1.arg.windows.platforms=x86|x64|ARM
```

and also with

```
codename1.arg.windows.buildType=Release
codename1.arg.windows.makeReleaseAppxbundle=false
codename1.arg.windows.platforms=x86|x64|ARM
```

And the resulting apps seem to install and run on my Windows 10 machine with no issues.

Comment: Thanks for the fix. I tried it soon afterwards and it seemed much better but I have just got back to it now and the old problems seem to be back. Could you have a look when you have a chance?

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me.  Which specific problem are you having?  You describe different issues (build errors and runtime crashes) in the initial post?

Comment: Unfortunately I am still getting similar issues as described in the original question. With makeReleaseAppxbundle=false the appxupload file contains an appxbundle that crashes on start (with the above error in Windows.UI.Xaml.dll). With makeReleaseAppxbundle=true my test app will run but my main app locks on a black screen on startup. I will try to recreate the latter issue in the test app if I get a chance next week.

Comment: I am getting this in the log file for the main app when built with makeReleaseAppxbundle=true: https://pastebin.pl/view/21267490

Comment: Does it still fail for you on Hello World?  I see that you're doing a GUI builder (legacy) app.  Does it still fail for you with just a bare bones GUI builder app?